# Python Group Repeated Values in List in a Sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to append some repeated values from a list into a sublist, let me explain with an example:

I have a variable called `array` that contains strings of uppercase letters and `$` symbols.

```
array = ['F', '$', '$', '$', 'D', '$', 'C']
```

My end goal is to have this array:

```
final_array = ['F', ['$', '$', '$'], 'D', ['$'], 'C']
```

As in the example, I need to group all `$` symbols that are togheter into sublist in the original `array`, I thought about iterating over the array and finding all symbols near the current `$` and then creating a second array, but I think maybe there is something more pythonic I can do, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools`

```
array = ['F', '$', '$', '$', 'D', '$', 'C']

from itertools import groupby

result = []
for key, group in groupby(array):
    if key == '$':
        result.append(list(group))
    else:
        result.append(key)

print(result)
```

You can of course shorten the for-loop to a comprehension:

```
result = [list(group) if key == '$' else key for key, group in groupby(array)]
```

Comment: not sure the case of `["F", "F"]` is handled as expected

Answer (score 1):

A general approach, that would work in every case (not just '$'):

```
array = ['F', '$', '$', '$', 'D', '$', 'C']
different_values = []
final_array = []
aux_array = []
old_value = None

for value in array:
    if value not in different_values:
        different_values.append(value)
        final_array.append(value)
        aux_array = []
    else:
        if value == old_value:
            aux_array = list(final_array[-1])
            del final_array[-1]
            aux_array.append(value)
            final_array.append(aux_array)
        else:
            aux_array = [value]
            final_array.append(aux_array)

    old_value = value


print(final_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little change from @rdas answer just in case we have an array with repeated values that we want to keep:

```
array = ['F', 'F', '$', '$', '$', 'D', '$', 'C']

result = []
for key, group in groupby(array):
    if key == '$':
        result.append(list(group))
    else:
        for g in list(group):
            result.append(g)
print(result)
# ['F', 'F', ['$', '$', '$'], 'D', ['$'], 'C']
```